# How to train existing GRNN in MATLAB?

Tags: neural-network, regression

I have created a GRNN using command:

```
net = newgrnn(inputs, output);
```

How do I train existing GRNN on new inputs in MATLAB? In other words, how to train net on other inputs?

Comment: did you tried to use train function after generating the net with newgrnn?

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro: It gives an error if we use train function. I tried something like this:

`network = newgrnn([1, 2, 3, 4]',[10]');
network = train(network, [2, 3, 4, 5]', [14]'); `

I got the error as: 

`Error using network/train (line 146)
NET.trainFcn is not defined.`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is that newgrnn is defined based on the training data. Therefore you cannot retrain the network unless you do it from the scratch. What I would suggest you is to use a different radial basis network that can be retrain such as the newrb. I added a simulation of such networks for a regression problem. Take into consideration that this is a complex regression as you have only partial coverage in the training data, and you should not expect much from either network. You can also use this simulation to try different architectures such as MLP.

CODE:

```
%% simulate data
X=linspace(0,20*pi,1250);
Y=sin(X)-X/20+rand(1,1250)*0.2;
Xtrain=X([250:500,550,600,650,700,750:1000]);
Ytrain=Y([250:500,550,600,650,700,750:1000]);


%% create a radial neural network through newrbe
spread=0.6;
net = newrbe(Xtrain,Ytrain,spread);
view (net)
Y_net = net(X);

%% create a radial neural network through newgrnn
spread=0.6;
net1 = newgrnn(Xtrain,Ytrain,spread);
view (net1)
Y_net1 = net1(X);

%% create a radial neural network through newrb and retrain with bayesian
spread=0.6;
net2 = newrb(Xtrain,Ytrain,0,spread,40);
view (net2)
Y_net2 = net2(X);

net3=net2;
net3.trainFcn='trainbr';
net3.trainParam.epochs = 1000;
net3 = train(net3,Xtrain,Ytrain);
view (net3)
Y_net3 = net3(X);

%% plot networks
h=figure;
plot(X,Y,'black'),hold on
plot(Xtrain,Ytrain,'blacko'),hold on
plot(X,Y_net1,'Color',[1,0,1])
plot(X,Y_net,'r')
plot(X,Y_net2,'g')
plot(X,Y_net3,'b')
axis([X(1),X(end),-5,2])
legend('original data','train data','newrbe','newgrnn','newrb','newrb-retrain')
```

OUTPUT:
[image: simulation of radial basis neural networks]

Answer (score 0):

GRNN can not be trained in the sense of backpropagation. It is single pass learning. It will assign new neuron for every input pattern so in order to train it just include the data point in the command newgrnn(1:n,1:m);